# ¿Cómo puedo guardar el contenido de un fichero de texto en una lista en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lista

Tengo un fichero de texto con las siguientes líneas:

```
55100515
55101515
55102515
```

Quiero pasarlo a una lista. He escrito el siguiente código:

```
input_file_path = "archivo.txt"

with open(input_file_path, "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        str = line.split()
        str_list = list.append()
print(str_list)
```

Sin la linea `str_list = list.append()` el programa da como resultado una lista por línea con un elemento por lista. Pero lo que quiero es que coloque una sola lista con los datos consecutivos.

Comment: `with open(input_file_path) as in_file: str_list = in_file.read().split()`

Comment: Funcionó. Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Según la documentación de [Input and Output](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files):

```
input_file_path = "archivo.txt"
with open(input_file_path, 'r') as f:
    myNames = [line.strip() for line in f]
print(myNames)
```

Comment: Ok, funcionó. Gracias.

Comment: Gracias! Puedes darlo por resuelto en la respuesta? Un saludo